# Reading erb form fields, Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Question about Rails4, I trying to retrieve the "Find Stuff" variable, in the erb form. This 
is a search field, using zurb foundation - so the extra styling annotations floating around.
I don't have a model as this is just a form for reading the search input field - which is 
in the  tag, with placeholder as "Find Stuff".

To use normal Rails4 terminology, I would
like to pass the value of the "Find Stuff" field to the salutation controller, and I tried 
many ways, but was unsuccessful, when I used render params[:post].inpect, it shows nil -the
variables that I pass to the controller, on clicking on the "Search" link_to, link. I tried adding an id field to the  tag, and that too showed nil on render params[:post].inspect.
Any help, thanks in anticipation.

hello.html.erb form below.

```
<html>
<body>
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="#">Hello World!</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
</li>
          </ul>
    <ul class="right">
        <li class="has-form">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="large-8 small-9 columns">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Find Stuff" > 
                </div>
                <div class="large-4 small-3 columns">
                  <%= link_to "", :controller => 
        'salutation', :action =>'hello', 
         :class=>"alert button expand"  %>

                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </section>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>                

   Controller follows

   Salutation Controller follows

class SalutationController < ApplicationController

def new
 @test = ''
end

def hello
 @message = 'Hello World!'
 @test = params[:Find_Stuff]
 end
end
```

Comment: Find stuff is a placeholder not the name of the field.

You don't have a full form or a submit button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your search box in a form element, give your input a name and away you go. You can use the rails form helpers as well - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html which has a nice intro to creating a search form

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <%= form_tag("/salutation/hello", method: "post") do %>
        <div class="large-8 small-9 columns">
            <%= text_field_tag(:find_stuff) %>
         </div>
         <div class="large-4 small-3 columns">
              <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
         </div>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: like these: changes routes file to take posts, change the controller action to search ie - /salutation/hello to /salutation/search; and the search action in the controller has only (for testing purposes) render text: params[:post].inspect - this gives "nil"

Answer (score 0):

Further to `@slapthelownote`'s answer, the reason you're getting an error is because you're not passing any params to your controller

We've got something like what you want working at http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk (top search box) -- using a `form_tag`

If you want to see live code, I'll be happy to post!

---

**Params**

Using a `form` allows you to set various variables & then submit them to the controller as you've set them. I'd recommend using the form in the other answer, but to understand how it works, you need to read up on the [Rails forms tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form)

Basically, the `params` hash is populated in the middleware of Rails -- from any data sent by HTTP to your backend

With links, you can only send [`GET`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms) params (`domain.com/route&params=value`), whilst with HTML forms, you can set `POST` params which are passed through the browser (not the URL)

Comment: had to use some changes it gave an error template missing on /salutation/search method - so changes it to salutation/hello- works here, and echoes test string